# installed local npm package is not symlinked

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have installed a local npm package via:

```
npm i ./my_modules/mypackage
```

It shows up in my dependencies as:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "mypackage": "file:my_modules/mypackage"
  }
```

when I look at the `node_modules` folder, it shows up in there as well, but it is not symlinked

there is no arrow icon in the explorer indicating it is symlinked

which means I have to rebuild every single time I want to see changes inside the local package

this only just started happening today, I'm not sure why it's not symlinking all of the sudden

how do I resolve this issue so that it symlinks properly? it used to do this automatically and now it isn't. I've even tried re-installing everything on my dev machine and it is still doing this behaviour.

normally when I install a local npm package it will symlink it properly, automatically

now, for whatever reason, it is not symlinking

EDIT

I've even tried using `npm link`

```
cd my_modules/mypackage
npm link
cd ../../
npm link mypackage
npm I ./my_modules/mypackage
```

still doesn't symlink.

Answer (score 0):

Some conflicts could happen. To resolve that go to the root of your npm package folder and call `npm unlink<package_name>` then in your test folder remove node_modules and even you can delete your package.json. After you reset that you can again go to the root of your npm package and call the `npm link` then install your local npm package in the test folder and test it out.